# Karate: Replace text at Envelope level

Tags: soap, karate

In the Envelope, I want to replace the ver=1 to ver=100
How can I replace the value at the Envelope level

<soap:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urnl="abc@**ver=1**">
soap:Header/
soap:Body
...
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>